# redirect after login through grails spring security facebook plugin?

Tags: grails, web, grails-plugin

How to redirect after a user logged in to application through spring security facebook plugin. Is there any success handler configuration for  facebook plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following JS in your view:

```
<facebookAuth:init>
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
         window.location.href = 'url where to redirect'
    });
</facebookAuth:init>
```

See https://github.com/splix/s2-facebook-example for complete example

Comment: Does the <facebook:init> code block only work for client-side authentication?

Comment: yes, <facebookAuth:init> is useful only for client-side authentication